# Query if HDR is active on windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, msdn

How do I programatically query the display settings to check if HDR mode is active on windows. I do not see a way to retrieve this information using [EnumDisplaySettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumdisplaysettingsa) function. Is there another API provided by windows to get that information?

Comment: @VictorGubin How is HDR related to the resolution? HDR is color/contrast, not size. Don't let the HD part fool you...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `IDXGIOutput6::GetDesc1()`.

If `DXGI_OUTPUT_DESC1::DXGI_COLOR_SPACE_TYPE==DXGI_COLOR_SPACE_RGB_FULL_G2048_NONE_P2020`, the display is in HDR mode.

documentation: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi1_6/ns-dxgi1_6-dxgi_output_desc1

From UWP, there is also `AdvancedColorInfo.CurrentAdvancedColorKind()` that will be equal to `AdvancedColorKind.HighDynamicRange`

documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.display.advancedcolorinfo

Answer (score 1):

First, In my knowledge, there is no api for check the current HDR mode provide by MSDN.

But I know the apis(in nvapi.h) to check HDR capabilities and turn on/off HDR mode.

```
NVAPI_INTERFACE NvAPI_Disp_GetHdrCapabilities(__in NvU32 displayId,__inout NV_HDR_CAPABILITIES *pHdrCapabilities);

NVAPI_INTERFACE NvAPI_Disp_HdrColorControl(__in NvU32 displayId, __inout NV_HDR_COLOR_DATA *pHdrColorData);
```

Hope this [document](https://developer.nvidia.com/displaying-hdr-nuts-and-bolts) could help you!
Or you can also turn to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/desktop/api/dxgi1_5/nn-dxgi1_5-idxgiswapchain4) for more information.However, there is only the "set" method